# Find and Edit the httpd.conf in plesk

Tags: apache, .htaccess, plesk, keep-alive

i want to Find and Edit the httpd.conf in plesk

i have vps  and i am new in plesk

i need to Enable keep-alive. i find this http://www.giftofspeed.com/enable-keep-alive/

so i add this in .htaccess

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Connection keep-alive
</ifModule>
```

i get Connection: None Detected useing Keep-Alive Test

but i dont where to edit

Comment: Good luck. Plesk takes over the machine and makes changes. You can't edit the default httpd.conf. You have to add custom code to `/var/www/vhosts/system/<domain_name>/conf/`. You should read the docs. it contains this info. http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/Doc/es-ES/online/plesk-linux-advanced-administration-guide/index.htm?fileName=72064.htm

Comment: thank you i have read many pages about this even this page ... so if i add this custom code ... can i make change like enable keep-alive

Comment: Yes that is where that stuff goes. If you try to change the main httpd.conf file plesk will overwrite it next time it updates. Anything you would normally put in httpd.conf that is custom like rules goes in that location.

Answer (score 0):

thank you Panama Jack

i have add this in .htaccess

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Connection keep-alive
</ifModule>
```

and add this in Additional directives for HTTP in plesk (Apache & nginx Settings)

```
#
# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
#
KeepAlive On

#
# MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
# during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
# We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
#
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

#
# KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
# same client on the same connection.
#
KeepAliveTimeout 15
```

in test i get Connection: keep-alive

but no thing change. in google test ( Improve Server Response Time )